# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS | Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I've just started using Ubuntu, before I was using Windows 10.

I'll go step by step to explain what I did and what is the problem.

**Installation:**

1. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the 'Device' dropdown
2. Click the CD Rom icon next to the 'FreeDOS' dropdown, then find your
   downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click 'Open' and then 'Start
3. Click 'Yes' when it asks to download Syslinux software
4. Click 'OK' **to write in DD mode, as write in ISO Image mode didn't work at all!**
5. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then 'OK' to continue
6. When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu

**The problem:**

**If UEFI enabled,** I have following message:  "[Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTdAP.png)"

**So I have to disable the UEFI in order to run Ubuntu, the steps are:**

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. In the boot menu I'm selecting 250GB 850 EVO MZ-75E250BW/EU drive.

Even, if I'm moving my hard drive to the first priory, saving the setting and then disabling UEFI, I'm having the same massage: "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media...."

[Also I have used bootinfosript, to make a summary of the boot.](http://paste2.org/xLZfPbB7)

Note: Just in case, my laptop is custom made by Scan computers:

1. 250GB 850 EVO MZ-75E250BW/EU £
2. 3XS LG15 Performance GTX
3. 3XS MVW-10
4. 15.6 N150RD FHDIPS 960 i7
5. 3XS Only 8GB 1.35V 1600 SODIMM
6. Arctic Silver 5 Paste 3.5g
7. Ssung Ultra Slim SU-208HB/BEBE

Comment: Generically you should install in UEFI mode wherever available. Select UEFI only in the UEFI settings if available; avoid UEFI+CSM (Legacy). Also keep in mind how it boots it's how it installs. A USB drive made in the way you described should boot fine in UEFI mode.